# In CKEditor, Not able to upload the Images.?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

i am using CKEditor (3.62), while uploading Images from image button the image is not loading in the CKEditor. How to solve this problem.?

Comment: do you have the permissions to save the image on the server? If the upload dialog appears and the upload starts but no image is inserted than the error might by serverside while saving it

Comment: My problem starts from , while i click "Browse server" in upload dialog box, there is a syntax error. not permit to upload the images..

Comment: ok. But if you are really searching for help you should post code, error logs, just more than these two lines above.

Answer (score 1):

am integrated ckfinder in ckeditor. while i uploading the images its getting script error, i.e., in ckfinder.html. i dont know how to setup the ckfinder in ckeditor. how to solve the issues.

[image: @philipp here is the script error page.]

Answer (score 1):

There might be some problem in giving paths.
Try doing following steps.
1. Download CKEditor and CKFinder. Integrated code may be available on http://dwij.co.in/ckeditor-ckfinder-integration-using-php/
2. Put extracted code of both in one folder inside xampp as below.
3. Create index file (index.html) which will be containing the editor as below code.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>CKEditor CKFinder Integration using PHP</h1>
        <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        filebrowserBrowseUrl : 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
        filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
        filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
        filebrowserUploadUrl : 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
        filebrowserImageUploadUrl : 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
        filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash'
    });
    CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, '../' );
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

so your folder structure will be something like this:

```
htdocs
|_integrated
    |_ckeditor
    |   |_config.js
    |   |_...
    |_ckfinder
    |   |_config.php
    |   |_...
    |_uploads
    |_index.html
```

1. Now open file config.php inside ckfinder & make following changes:

   ```
   function CheckAuthentication() {
       // WARNING : DO NOT simply return "true". By doing so, you are allowing
       // "anyone" to upload and list the files in your server. You must implement
       // some kind of session validation here. Even something very simple as...
       // return isset($_SESSION['IsAuthorized']) && $_SESSION['IsAuthorized'];
       return true; // not good option though; go for sessions
   }
   $baseUrl = 'http://localhost/integrated/uploads/';
   $enabled = true;
   $config['SecureImageUploads'] = false;
   $config['ChmodFolders'] = 0777 ;
   ```
2. Now open url `http://localhost/integrated/` and try uploading image.